# Server http2 settings

Tags: okhttp

I want to get the initial HTTP2 setting that the server sent for HTTP/2 connection using okhttp 5.0.0-alpha.10 library

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = okHttpClient.sslSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("app.test.com", 443);
Http2Connection connection = new Http2Connection.Builder(true, TaskRunner.INSTANCE)
    .socket(socket)
    .build();
connection.start();

getInitialWindowSize ??
getMaxConcurrentStreams() ??
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the code in the okhttp3.internal package is intended for end-users to use, including the `Http2Connection` class.

Comment: I want to determine the connection pool size based on the server max streams, header table size, window size and other parameters. Can I make a call with OkHTTP client to get these settings from server ?

Comment: No, and I don't think the connection pool size is very interesting for HTTP/2. OkHttp will use the server max streams and the number of in-flight requests automatically.